Android Compose AnchoredDraggable - Listen for Completed Drag
I'm using Compose's AnchoredDraggable to drag some items vertically, and I want to invoke a callback each time one reaches the end anchor (specifically the end anchor - I don't want to listen for when the item goes back to the start anchor). Is there a way I can listen for this? I tried using MutableInteractionSource and then calling collectIsDraggedAsState() to know when to invoke my callback, but it gets triggered immediately when a drag starts, not when it finishes.
What I have:
val state = remember {
    AnchoredDraggableState(
        initialValue = DragAnchor.START,
        positionalThreshold = { distance: Float -> distance * 0.5f },
        velocityThreshold = { with(density) { 100.dp.toPx() } },
        animationSpec = tween(),
    )
}
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isDragged = interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()

if (isDragged.value) {
    onDragComplete() // callback I want to invoke
}

MyComposable(
    // omitted the other modifiers
    modifier = Modifier
        .anchoredDraggable(
            state = state,
            orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
            reverseDirection = false,
            interactionSource = interactionSource
        )
)


You can do like so:
LaunchedEffect(state.settledValue) {
    if (state.settledValue == End) onDragComplete()
}

Simply listen for the settledValue. It took me some time to figure this in my own project too since there is not extensive documentation for the moment.

You can capture changes to the AnchoredDebuggableState using LaunchedEffect in combination with snapshotFlow inside a @Composable function.
val anchoredDraggableState = remember() {
    AnchoredDraggableState(...))
}

LaunchedEffect(anchoredDraggableState) {
    snapshotFlow { anchoredDraggableState }.collect { state ->
        // you can handle the state change here
    }
}


Did you mean the AnchoredDraggableState, not the AnchoredDebuggableState?
